# Remove entire row if cell is not highlighted

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to go through range of cells and do the following:
If cell has background color then skip. If no background color then delete entire row.

What is wrong in my current code?

```
Sub RemoveRowsThatAreNotHighlighted123()

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Range("A2:L" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row)

    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 0 Then cell.EntireRow.Delete
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `xlColorIndexNone` instead of `0`:

Furthermore, in deleting rows it's always recommended to loop backwards, as follows:

```
Sub RemoveRowsThatAreNotHighlighted123()
    Dim iRow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main") ' reference your workbook and worksheet
        With .Range("A2:L" & .Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row) ' reference referenced worksheet range from A2 down to column C last not empty cell before first empty one
            For iRow = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1 ' loop from referenced range last row backwards
                If .Rows(iRow).Interior.ColorIndex = -4142 Then .Rows(iRow).EntireRow.Delete ' if alll referenced range current row cells have no background then delete row
            Next
        End With
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm.. for some reason this removes all the data on the sheet